# Lock body scrolling on div mouseover but maintain position

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, scroll

I know there are a few other questions relating to this (including one from me a while ago), but I'm looking for a way to improve the only solution I've found to work.

I'm trying to make it so that I can use the mouse wheel for scroll a height limited and `overflow: scroll;` `<div>`, and one that will continue to work when the `<div>` is contained within a `<div>` whose content comes from an AJAX call.

On my web travels I happened upon this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/eXQf3/33/.  Unfortunately I cannot get this to work when the data is called from an AJAX call - I have no idea why this is happening, so if anyone is aware of this issue I'd appreciate some advice!

I've gone a little off topic though, because my question relates to the only solution I've found that at least works: onmouseover class adding.

**DIV**

```
<div onmouseover="$('html').addClass('noscroll');" 
     onmouseout="$('html').removeClass('noscroll');" 
     style="overflow:auto;max-height: 200px;">Data that is long</div>
```

**CSS Class**

```
html.noscroll
{
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've been using this code thinking it worked flawlessly, however I've just found that on smaller monitors it throws up a much more annoying issue: jumping back to the top of the screen!

It seems that when the `position: fixed;` is triggered it does disable the scrollbar and keep it visible (which I want) but it also moves the scrollbar all the way to the top again, and as my scrollable div is half way down the page it makes it impossible to use.

Comment: Are you looking on my solution? Is it working?

Answer (score 1):

For this part:

> Unfortunately I cannot get this to work when the data is called from an AJAX call - I have no idea why this is happening, so if anyone is aware of this issue I'd appreciate some advice!

You need change little code:

```
$('#abs').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
```

[After changes](http://jsfiddle.net/eXQf3/338/)

`bind` working only for exist elements and cannot be attached to elements gets via ajax. From jQuery site:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

[Read more about .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

So try change your code to this which I show you and give me feedback after changes.